# Why the horizon increases in the formation of blackhole with radiation

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

I am reading the lecture notes given by Professor Leonard Susskind. It's said the horizon appears and gets bigger as the in-falling photon sphere further falls in. Photon sphere here is a falling shell not the one at $R=3MG$.

However, as I can imagine, if the photon sphere presented, the mass is fixed. From Newton's theorem, we can always put the mass at the center point. Isn't that the horizon is fixed no matter how far away this in-falling photon sphere is, even it has an infinity radius? In symbol, the horizon is at $R=2MG$ no matter where the photon sphere is.

Comment: The question seems to be a bit jumbled. The photon sphere is defined by the black hole mass, and is certainly not falling in. Are you are asking how the horizon *looks* to an infalling observer, or are you talking about a case where radiation falling into the black hole makes it grow over time?

Comment: My take is that what OP is calling a “photon sphere” is actually a “null dust shell”, that is the simplest model of black hole collapse.

Comment: A.V.S is right, the photon sphere here is a falling shell not the one at 3MG. I will clarify it in my question.

Comment: @safesphere The original text said the inner of the sphere is flat space. Thus, I guess no $m$ inside. The falling shell of photon per se is the black hole. Even if there is $m$, there still shouldn't exist any increase of horizon as I can imagine. The horizon is fixed when the shell is infinity far away or at least finite distance away. I can imagine that an accumulating photon sphere will cause increase in horizon. However, I read several times and didn't see any kind of such conditions.